# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_aData' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I was having a problem regarding Datatables, when i try to edit my data from the datatable it goes all well, after the datatable refreshes my edit / delete buttons does not work and it throws this kind of error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_aData' of undefined`.

Here is my UI for the datatable.
[Datatable image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkGis.png)

Here is my code for the event for the edit.

```
$('#template_table tbody').on('click','.update',function(){
    var closestRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    var data = templateTable.row(closestRow).data();
    console.log(data);
    tableId = data.id;
    $('#modal-title').text('Update Template');
    $('#alert_lvl').val(data.alert_lvl);
    $('#internal_alert').val(data.internal_alert);
    $('#scenario').val(data.possible_scenario);
    $('#response').val(data.recommended_response);
    $('#submit_template').text("UPDATE");
    $('#template_modal').modal('toggle');
});
```

And this is my save function that will refresh the datatable to show the updated one.

```
function reloadTable() {
    $('#template_table').DataTable().clear();
    $('#template_table').DataTable().destroy();
    template_table = $('#template_table').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": false,
        "scrollX": true,
        "ajax": '../communications/fetchalltemplate',
        columns: [
            { "data" : "id" , title:"ID"},
            { "data" : "alert_lvl", title:"ALERT LEVEL"},
            { "data" : "internal_alert", title:"INTERNAL ALERT"},
            { "data" : "possible_scenario", title:"POSSIBLE SCENARIO"},
            { "data" : "recommended_response", title:"RECOMMENDED RESPONSE"},
            { "data" : "last_update_by", title:"LATEST MODIFICATION"},
            { "data" : "functions", title: "*"}
        ]
    });
}
```

then if i hit update again. i throws the error right here in this part.

```
var data = templateTable.row(closestRow).data();
```

Thank you in advance if you can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I initialize the datatable every time i reload the datatable and it worked properly.

under reloadTable function.

> `var templateTable = $('#template_table').DataTable();`

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is in the declaration of `closestRow` variable.

According to [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), the .closest() function searches for the closest element (respecting the given selector) traversing the DOM *upwards*.

This means that since you're binding this action to the click on the table's body, you're basically searching for a `<tr>` element among the parents of that table.

You can do what you want with another selection method

```
var closestRow = $(this).children('tr:first');
```